# Unity 2d расположение элемента на экране

Tags: c#, unity3d, gui, экран

Делаю в Unity несколько кнопок, красиво располагаю их относительно друг друга, указывая расположения в пикселях. Разумеется, подобный подход не работает на устройствах с разным разрешением экрана, поэтому я пользуюсь `Screen.heigth` и `Screen.wigth`. Проблема в том что можно указать в делителях только целые числа, поэтому кнопки относительно друг друга ориентированны некрасиво. т.е. я могу сделать `Screen.heigth/3` и `Screen.width/3` и у меня элемент ПРИМЕРНО встанет куда надо. Идеально было бы сделать `Screen.heigth/2.5`, но так нельзя. Размещаю элемент RepeatButton

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Почему только целые? Используй кнопки UI и расставляй их в редакторе.
Попробуй так:

```
Screen.height/2.5f
```

Comment: Спасибо, а почему именно UI кнопки? Просто для RepeatButton я знаю код, он у меня такой 
`void OnGUI()
    {
        if (GUI.RepeatButton(new Rect(0, 225, 90, 90), "Down"))
        {
            dir = -Vector2.up; 
        }`
А как сделать подобное с UI кнопкой?

Comment: Удобно.  Читай справку. http://unity3d.com/ru/learn/tutorials/topics/user-interface-ui/ui-button

Comment: Хорошо, это понял. Но есть одно то - когда стартую игру, кнопки которые я писал в скрипте (RepeatButton) видны, а те что расположил вручную(UI) не видны

Comment: В другой слой попали. Или под  RepeatButton. Хз, много чего может быть. Используй то что тебе удобней и то что ты знаешь. Основная проблема решена, зачем придумывать себе еще.

Comment: Кнопки не отображались потому что я пытался их положить в поле камеры, как остальные объекты. А их надо класть в их Canvas, причем в той же позиции, в которой я бы хотел видеть их в поле камеры. Такие дела.